# Gimp from command line

Tags: linux, image, png, gimp

I used Gimp to export a PNG to another without color values from transparent pixels. Is there ay way to do the same from the command line? I'm going to use this script from a php.
The option in Gimp UI is "Save color values from transparent pixels" unchecked.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to script a huge, interactive GUI program like the Gimp, how about just using a simple command line image tool like ImageMagick's `convert`. Here's the example that does exactly this from their [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/):

```
convert moon.png -background HotPink -alpha Background moon_hotpink.png
```

Comment: Thanks I only used convert monkey4.png -alpha  Background monkey5.png